# How can i create this sort of table layout on an android application?

Tags: android, user-interface, grid-layout

Good Day

I was wondering if anybody would be able to help me out. While creating an android application, I've been trying to design a UI that looks similar to this, but have not managed to get it quite right.

[Table layout for an application timetable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1z3Y.png)

Can anyone please suggest a way to get such a layout with the days and times, where i could probably use a text view inside each cell.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a master linearLayout (horizontal), then inside it, create three linearLayout (all vertical). Inside each create 24 linearLayout with a TextView. Wrap the 24 lineaLayout (each for one hour) with a master linearLayout. and wrap that master linearLayout with a scrollView to activate your scrolling. 
Hope you understood it correctly. Cheers.